# Surface plot over complex plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using the `pgfplots` package in an attempt to draw the function `s(p0) = sign(Re p0) sign(Im p0)`, where `p0` is a complex number. What I have so far is

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ticks=none,
        xlabel=$\mathrm{Re}(p_0)$,
        ylabel=$\mathrm{Im}(p_0)$,
        zlabel=$s(p_0)$]

    \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,color=DarkBlue!20]{x/abs(x)*y/abs(y)};
    \addplot3[mesh,domain=-1:1,color=black,samples=10]{0};% complex plane

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this rather ugly plot.

[image]

What I would like to have is something akin to this:

[image]

So my question is, how can I

1. remove those annoying "cliffs",
2. add low-opacity color to the complex plane, i.e. the mesh at `z = 0`
3. add proper depth perception,
4. add numbers but no markers sparingly to the axes, i.e. just -1, 0, and 1, and
5. apply nicer colors not only to the mesh but the actual surface of the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. remove those annoying "cliffs"

Pgfplots allows to exclude parts of surfaces using two different ways: either by assigning "unbounded coords" (like z=nan) for specific data points or by using "unbounded color data" (point meta=nan).

Below, I chose to use "unbounded color data" and added a suitable color data by means of `point meta={abs(x) < 1e-3 || abs(y) < 1e-3 ? nan : z}` . This means that the colordata is a *scalar* value which is `nan` for x ~ 0 and y ~0 and is the `z` value otherwise. This means that the axis in the middle becomes invisible (i.e. the adjacent surface segments are omitted).

Details: see section "4.5.14 Interrupted Plots" in the manual.

2. "add low-opacity color to the complex plane"

I added `opacity=0.7` to its option list. Any kind of tikz drawing option can be added, and this is how opacity is configured. Please refer to the manual of tikz for a complete list of graphics state options (pgfmanual.pdf)

3. "add proper depth perception"

This something that pgfplots simply cannot do at the time of this writing.
In order to combine multiple overlapping surfaces, you have two choices: resort to another 3d visualization tool or reorder the surface segments manually.

Since this question is about pgfplots, I followed the second approach. In my case, this results in *two* surfaces for the jump plot: one above and one below the complex plane. To this end, I simply modified the already existing filter for `point meta` by adding `z>0` or `z<0`, respectively. See below.

4. "Add numbers but no markers"

I used `xtick distance` combined and `tickwidth` below

5. "apply nicer colors"

What does "nicer" mean? Personally, I like it if the mesh color is "close" to the surface color; something that `pgfplots` does by default. Consequently, I simply reverted your color override to the default. The default is to map the scalar color data into a `colormap`. Details about this can be found in the pgfplots manual or may be subject of a follow-up question.

I chose colors for the complex plane explicitly as its colormap mapping is hard to control (it has no min/max). You can, of course, easily generalize it to the other two segments.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$\mathrm{Re}(p_0)$,
        ylabel=$\mathrm{Im}(p_0)$,
        zlabel=$s(p_0)$,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        ztick distance=1,
        tickwidth=0pt,
    ]

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-1:1,%color=DarkBlue!20,
        point meta={abs(x) < 1e-3 || abs(y) < 1e-3 || z > 0 ? nan : z},
    ] {x/abs(x)*y/abs(y)};

    \addplot3[
        %mesh,
        surf,
        domain=-1:1,
        opacity=0.7,
        blue!50!white,faceted color={blue},
        %color=black,
        samples=10,
    ]{0};% complex plane

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-1:1,%color=DarkBlue!20,
        point meta={abs(x) < 1e-3 || abs(y) < 1e-3 || z < 0 ? nan : z},
    ] {x/abs(x)*y/abs(y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this problem after some time, I think the simplest solution is probably to just specify coordinates rather than plot the actual function. This approach improves both compile time and file size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$\Re(p_0)$,
        ylabel=$\Im(p_0)$,
        zlabel=$s(p_0)$,
        domain=-1:1,
        surf,shader=flat,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        ztick distance=1,
        tickwidth=0pt
    ]

    \addplot3[blue!20] coordinates {
        (-1,1,-1) (0,1,-1)

        (-1,0,-1) (0,0,-1)
    };

    \addplot3[blue!20] coordinates {
        (1,-1,-1) (0,-1,-1)

        (1,0,-1) (0,0,-1)
    };

    % Zero plane
    \addplot3[
        gray,opacity=0.1,
        samples=2,
    ]{0};

    \addplot3[orange!80] coordinates {      
        (0,0,1) (1,0,1)

        (0,1,1) (1,1,1)
    };

    \addplot3[orange!80] coordinates {      
        (0,0,1) (-1,0,1)

        (0,-1,1) (-1,-1,1)
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```